# Canvas within a responsive materialize css div

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, materialize

I'm trying to implement whiteboard with pencil and eraser using HTML 5 canvas and JavaScript. It is working fine if I place canvas tag with in the body tag. But if I move the same canvas tag inside a responsive row of materialize css row, its not adapting as per parent div. Pencil and Eraser are not working. Can you suggest me how can I make it responsive?

Here is the js code

```
$(document)
    .ready(
        function () {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var canvasx = $(canvas).offset().left;
            var canvasy = $(canvas).offset().top;
            var last_mousex = last_mousey = 0;
            var mousex = mousey = 0;
            var mousedown = false;
            var tooltype = 'draw';

            // Mousedown
            $(canvas).on('mousedown', function (e) {
                last_mousex = mousex = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasx);
                last_mousey = mousey = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasy);
                mousedown = true;
            });

            // Mouseup
            $(canvas).on('mouseup', function (e) {
                mousedown = false;
            });

            // Mousemove
            $(canvas)
                .on(
                    'mousemove',
                    function (e) {
                        mousex = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasx);
                        mousey = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasy);
                        if (mousedown) {
                            ctx.beginPath();
                            if (tooltype == 'draw') {
                                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
                                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                                ctx.lineWidth = 3;
                            } else {
                                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
                                ctx.lineWidth = 10;
                            }
                            ctx
                                .moveTo(last_mousex,
                                    last_mousey);
                            ctx.lineTo(mousex, mousey);
                            ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
                            ctx.stroke();
                        }
                        last_mousex = mousex;
                        last_mousey = mousey;

                    });


            use_tool = function (tool) {
                tooltype = tool;
            }
        });
```

Below is the css

```
#canvas {
    cursor: crosshair;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Below is html grid

```
<div id="whiteboard-container" class="row">
    <div class="center col s12">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <input type="button" value="draw" onclick="use_tool('draw');" /> <input
                    type="button" value="erase" onclick="use_tool('erase');" />
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it work within the div?

Answer (score 0):

### DOM [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) properties

This is a pure JS solution.

#### DOM [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) offset

You can use the [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) read only properties [`offsetX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) and [`offsetY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetY) to get relative coordinates of mouse events.

**Notes**

- I do not know if these are passed on by jQuery

#### DOM [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) page

Alternatively you can use the [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) read only properties [`pageX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX) and [`pageY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageY)  and subtract the canvas element position and page scroll position.

```
const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
mouseX = event.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;   
mouseY = event.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
```

**Notes**

- [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollX){X,Y] are DOM [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) (or [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) in page context) properties
- canvas padding, border, and box model will effect the bounds. See [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) for details
- I do not know if these ([`pageX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX), [`pageY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageY)) are passed on by jQuery

#### jQuery

[jQuery is obsolete](https://love2dev.com/blog/jquery-obsolete/). There are no browsers that require DOM legacy support [IE is dead](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-ie-support). Using jQuery only slows your page down while providing no benefit.

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm a newbie in in these. I primarily work in backend technologies. This is difficult to grasp quickly. I'm looking for a working solution. Will try to read more about it.